# Ant task "javac" was successful but doesn't produce any output

Tags: ant, build, javac

I'm trying to compile a project using ant. I guess the "javac" task was successful as i can see the following message on the console:
[javac] Compiling 151 source file to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project1/workspace/build
Here is the complete output of the command "ant compile"

```
clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project1/workspace/build
   [delete] Deleting directory /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project1/workspace/docs
   [delete] Deleting directory /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project1/workspace/dist

makedir:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project1/workspace/build
    [mkdir] Created dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project1/workspace/docs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project1/workspace/dist

compile:
    [javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project1/workspace/build.xml:43: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 151 source file to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project1/workspace/build
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

**The problem is there is nothing produced in the folder "build" !**
I'm using the same build.xml template file in other projects and it works very well, but here i can't understand why i can't find the compiled sources in the build folder.
Please help.
Here is my build.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="project1" default="main" basedir=".">
  <!-- Sets variables which can later be used. -->
  <!-- The value of a property is accessed via ${} -->
  <property name="src.dir" location="src" />
  <property name="lib.dir" location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" />
  <property name="server.common.lib.dir" location="/home/ghali/jboss-5.1.0.GA/common/lib" />
  <property name="server.lib.dir" location="/home/ghali/jboss-5.1.0.GA/lib" />
  <property name="build.dir" location="build" />
  <property name="dist.dir" location="dist" />
  <property name="docs.dir" location="docs" />
  <!--
    Create a classpath container which can be later used in the ant task
  -->
  <path id="build.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
      <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${server.common.lib.dir}">
      <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${server.lib.dir}">
      <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
  </path>

  <!-- Deletes the existing build, docs and dist directory-->
  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${docs.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
  </target>

  <!-- Creates the  build, docs and dist directory-->
  <target name="makedir">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${docs.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
  </target>

  <!-- Compiles the java code -->
  <target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir">
    <javac destdir="${build.dir}" classpathref="build.classpath" debug="true">
      <src path="${src.dir}" />
    </javac>
  </target>

<!-- Creates Javadoc -->
  <target name="docs" depends="compile">
    <javadoc sourcepath="${src.dir}" destdir="${docs.dir}">
      <!-- Define which files / directory should get included, we include all -->
       <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <include name="**" />
           </fileset>
    </javadoc>
  </target>

  <!--Creates the deployable jar file  -->
  <target name="package" depends="compile">
    <war destfile="${dist.dir}/project1.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
      <fileset dir="WebContent" />
      <lib dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" />
      <classes dir="${build.dir}" />
    </war>
  </target>

  <target name="main" depends="compile, package, docs">
    <description>Main target</description>
  </target>

</project>
```

Comment: What about the folder build2`? This is where your output is being stored.

Comment: Nothing in build2 folder also.
I edited the question and change build2 to build.

Comment: I see `[javac] Compiling 151 source file to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project1/workspace/build`. Is this the directory you're checking?

Comment: yes it's the directory i'm checking.

Comment: Is your jenkins slave running as root? And are you checking the dir as a non-root user? Do a `sudo ls -la /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project1/workspace/build`

Comment: Good point! The build may be on a slave.

Comment: @aflat : 
I'm not yet using jenkins. I'm executing the compilation from command line. The weird thing is that everything is ok on my collegue machine. The problem exists only on my machine.<br /> I have tried deleting the project and checking it out again but nothing changed.

Comment: try an `ant -d compile` and see if there is more output

Comment: @aflat : I tried ant -d compile and ant -v but nothing special in the output.

Comment: Did you resolve this?  I am experiencing this problem now.  My build was working flawlessly for months and suddenly ant is launching javac which claims to be compiling over 200 files, but produces no class files in the listed output directory.  No changes made to build.xml, just java file changes.

Comment: Interesting.  Changing a few imports in one class seems to have gotten it going again.  Some of my import lines were getting pretty long, I will test that to see if it might be contributing.  (Just mind dumping here in case it might help someone else since I don't have a hard answer yet.)